# cfthrow is this how you use it? (from Adobe's doc)

Tags: exception, coldfusion

I was reading the [documentation for cfthrow](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Errors_15.html) and came accross this

> When to use the cfthrow tag
>
> Use the cfthrow tag when your application can identify and handle
>   application-specific errors. One typical use for the cfthrow tag is in
>   implementing custom data validation. The cfthrow tag is also useful
>   for throwing errors from a custom tag page to the calling page.
>
> For example, on a form action page or custom tag used to set a
>   password, the application can determine whether the password entered
>   is a minimum length, or contains both letters and number, and throw an
>   error with a message that indicates the password rule that was broken.
>   The cfcatch block handles the error and tells the user how to correct
>   the problem.

Have I been doing it wrong all this time or is this just a terrible use-case?

I was taught that exceptions shouldn't be used to handle regular application flow but for stuff that is somewhat out of your control.  For example, a file being locked when you go to write to it.

A user breaking a password rule doesn't quite sound like something that's out of your control.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question?

Comment: @baynezy yes, I always accept an answer.  In this case I really had a hard time choosing so it took me a while sorry :)

Comment: Oh I wasn't chasing. I just wanted to know if you needed more.

Comment: @baynezy no, I think I just need to get out of my head what was hammered in while in school that exception are expensive and therefore to be used for exceptional things.  Once I can do that, I should be ok ;)

Comment: no problem. I hope we helped, it is a complicated subject full of opinion and not much hard fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a poor example not a poor use case. I personally would pass in the parameters to a validation function and return a result that contained a pass or fail and a collection of failure messages to display to the user.

How I use exceptions is as follows.

**Within functions**. Let's say that you have a function that you are getting some data from the database and you are then constructing a structure from it. If the query returned has no values you have several options:-

1. You could return an empty structure and let the calling code deduce the problem from the fact the structure is empty. This is not ideal because then the application has to have complicated logic to address the missing data.
2. You could return a more complex datatype where one property is whether the process went ok and the actual data. Again this is not optimal as you have to then make this access the property on every call when the majority of the time you have data and again your application is dealing with this issue.
3. Or you could raise a custom exception with cfthrow indicating that there is no record that matches. This then means that you can choose to ignore the prospect of this error happening and let it bubble up to the onError handler or you could surround it in a try catch statement and deal with it there and then. This keeps your API clean and sensible.

**Wrapping external errors** let's say that you connect to an external API using cfhttp over https. Now this requires installing the certificate in your keystore otherwise it throws an error. If this certificate gets updated then it will start erroring again. In this instance I would wrap the call in a try catch and should this be the error I would wrap that in my own custom exception with a message detailing that we need to update the cert in the keystore so that any developer debugging it knows what to do to fix it without having to work it out. If it is not that particular error then I would cfrethrow it so that it bubbles up and is dealt with by whatever exception handling logic is above the call.

These are just a few examples, but there are more. To summarise I would say that throwing exceptions is a way of communicating up through the tiers of an application when something has occurred that is not the hoped for behaviour while keeping your API/Application logic clean and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to your discretion. It's extremely common in many languages to use exceptions for everything, including input validation.

Importantly, exceptions have nothing to do with something being in your control or not. For example, suppose that you have a fairly long and complicated module that uploads a file. There are many fail points in something like that: the file could be too big, the file could be the wrong format, etc. Without exceptions your only option is a lot of if/then checks and some kind of status return at the very end. With exceptions, all you have to do is use a set of cfthrows:

```
<cfthrow type="FileUpload.TooBig" message="The file size was #FileSize#, but the maximum size allowed is #MaxFileSize#">

<cfthrow type="FileUpload.WrongType" message="The file type was #FilType#, but the accepted types are #AcceptedTypeList#">
```

Then, whatever is calling the file upload function can catch either with `<cfcatch type="FileUpload">` or catch a specific one (e.g. `<cfcatch type="FileUpload.WrongType">`).

Also, technically a user breaking a password *is* out of your control, in the sense that the user has determined the value for the password. That said, I loathe password rules as invariably they make it harder, not easier, to maintain security.

Comment: Isn't a throw fairly expensive in term of resource usage though? It contains a lot more than just the "message" part.  I've learned exception handling with .NET and when an exception is being thrown you can certainly "feel" it.  I usually use exceptions in my components being called by "others".  I expect them to wrap it in a try/catch but if possible avoid the condition that would trigger an exception.  So with the password example, I would throw in the CFC but fully expect the caller to have validated their stuff before.  The throw is there as a last line of defense to protect them.

Comment: A better example would be creating a file in a non-existant directory. You could simply catch the error create the directory and then retry... but aren't you better off saving yourself the overhead and check with DirectoryExists(path) before trying to write in it?

Comment: @jfrobishow I don't think it's *so* resource expensive that it outweighs the benefits from more readable code. Considering we're talking about a web application here, doing things like optimizing queries are going to make a much bigger dent in performance slowdowns than avoiding exceptions. In Python exceptions are almost *always* considered best practice rather than testing. The logic is: if it's unlikely for the exception to happen, then most of the time it will be faster to not do the test first, and just assume that it will work, then handle the rare case that something is wrong.